# How to capture all matches for an incrementing Xpath query in another single XPath query?

Tags: xml, xpath

Twenty elements of the same type on a certain page can be found with following XPaths:

*//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[**1**]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span
//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[**2**]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span*

up to

*//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[**20**]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span*

(The full XPath is actually `/html/body/div/div[5]/div[4]/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/span` but the above abbrevation works well).

What I want to achieve: Instead of looping over a range from 1 to 20 (as `i`), I wish to somehow modify the general Xpath:

```
//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[i]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span
```

So that I can capture all 20 matches in one go. How best can this be achieved?

Comment: Note: I've already tried leaving out the part of the expression to the left of and including the index div, but it ends up not catching all matches.

Answer (score 3):

You can use position function in condition `[position() >= 1 and position() <= 20]`

```
//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[position() >= 1 and position() <= 20]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span
```